# strstr C function is functioning abnormally

Tags: c, text-parsing, strstr

For the C project coming up, the goal is to read in a CSV file with the first two lines listing the row and column lengths like

```
attributes: 23
lines: 1000
e,x,y,n,t,l,f,c,b,p,e,r,s,y,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,y,p
e,b,y,y,t,l,f,c,b,n,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,m
e,x,f,y,t,l,f,w,n,w,t,b,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,v,d
e,s,f,g,f,n,f,c,n,k,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,v,u
```

The thing is, I don't know if future file inputs will be of the same row/column lengths, so I'm implementing a `determineFormat` function to read those first two lines, which will be used for building the data structures.

In order to do this, I need to match a substring to the current line.  If it matches, then `fscanf` is used to read in the line and extract the length integers.  However, this code isn't working, as the entire `strstr` function is getting skipped over in ddd.

```
int lineCount, attrCount; //global variables

void determineFormats(FILE *incoming){

    char *curLine= emalloc(CLINPUT);
    int i;
    char *ptr=NULL;

    for (i=0; i<2; i++){
        if (fgets(curLine, CLINPUT, incoming) != NULL){
            ptr= strstr(curLine, "attrib");  //this line is skipped over

            if (ptr!= NULL)
                fscanf(incoming, "attributes: %d", &attrCount);

            else 
                fscanf(incoming, "lines: %d", &lineCount);  

        }
    }

    printf("Attribute Count for the input file is: %d\n", attrCount);
    printf("Line count is: %d\n", lineCount);

}
```

My thinking for the if/else block is since there are only two lines of interest to this function, and they're both at the head of the file, just scan each line and test if the string matches.  If it does, then the non-null conditional is run, otherwise the other conditional is executed.  However, in this case, the `strstr` function is getting skipped.

**Extra Info**

Some of the comments made me go back and double check.

CLINPUT is defined to be 100, or roughly 40% again the number of characters to read from each line.

This is the output from ddd when `ptr= strstr(curLine, "attrib");` is called:

```
0xb7eeaff0 in strstr () from /lib/libc.so.6
Single stepping until exit from function strstr,
which has no line number information.
```

Once this happens, the line indicator disappears, and single stepping (F5) from that point returns to the calling function.

Comment: Erm, that's not a CSV file. **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues

Comment: Bug in stackoverflow's bold mini-markup =) Should have used non-greedy regexes

Comment: Yeah ... I think it still makes the point though :)

Comment: Yep. You are 100% correct in the definition. It's just nice to see bugs in websites.

Comment: You forgot to free the memory right there...

Comment: @Brian Roach, acually, for the most part it is a CSV, as I edited the question to include a sample of the input data.  This is beside the point though, as just what does your comment have to do with my question?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko, what memory are you talking about?  The skipped function is occuring before any `free()` call would occur.

Comment: I can guarantee you that `strstr` isn't being "skipped". Either `fgets()` is returning NULL or `strstr` is.

Comment: What is CLINPUT defined to be? I think the problem is that you're either reading too little from the `attributes` line or too much` from the `lines` line, so your `fscanf` isn't applied at the correct location in the file.

Comment: I'm sure some good'ol `printf`'s would help you to find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strstr is working good. Problem is that fscanf will read **next** line since current already read.

Here's more correct way

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    if (fgets(curLine, CLINPUT, incoming) != NULL){
        if (strstr(curLine, "attributes:")) {
            sscanf(curLine, "attributes: %d", &attrCount);
        } else if (strstr(curLine, "lines:")) {
            sscanf(curLine, "lines: %d", &lineCount);  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It was the change to sscanf from fscanf that did the trick!  Thanks!